# NEO4J: find a node according to multiple relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I hope to find a node according to multiple relationship to other nodes.
For example, find a movie acted by actor A, directed by B and filmed by C.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Perhaps START would do that but since it needs legacy index, I prefer match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to string multiple matches together, such as:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a:Actor),
      (m:Movie)<-[:DIRECTED]-(d:Director),
      (m:Movie)<-[:FILMED_BY]-(f:Filmer)
```

or:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a:Actor)
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:DIRECTED]-(d:Director)
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:FILMED_BY]-(f:Filmer)
```

Note: I haven't tested this, but I believe both styles should work. And... for brevity, I left out details such as specifying actor/director/filmer name, and the `RETURN` portion. (and I made an assumption you were using labels; again, just an example on how to accomplish this).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works perfectly. But I wonder whether or not NEO4J is good for finding nodes between only two group of nodes. For example, a group of films and a group of actors. I hope to find films according to several actors or vice versa and the number of actor provided is undefined. Maybe in this case MongDB and his index is better for that search function? what do you think?

Comment: I don't think we should be going with additional questions in the comments (esp asking about MongoDB, which is a *completely* different type of database engine, and graph vs document engine is not a simple answer).